# Replace XML Attributes using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

Currently want to replace the from, to and subject attributes of an XML file using a PowerShell script.

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<elmah>
 <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="SqlServer" />
    <errorMail from="test@test.org" to="test@test.co.uk" cc="" subject="Error email title"/>
    <errorFilter>
    <test>
     </test>
 </errorFilter>
</elmah>
```

I have tried the following foreach loop but this doesnt seem update the attributes:

```
$xmlDoc = [XML](Get-Content "$path\Web.config")
foreach ($item in  $xmlDoc.configuration.elmah.errorMail){
{$item.from = 'test1@test1.org'}
{$item.to = 'test2@test2.org'}
{$item.subject = 'test3'}
}
$xmlDoc.Save("$path\Web.config")
```

Anyone help with this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *wrapping the assignment in a scriptblock* which will probably introduce new variables and prevent the properties in the xml from beeing updated. So just **remove the curly brackets**:

```
$xmlDoc = [XML](Get-Content "$path\Web.config")
foreach ($item in  $xmlDoc.configuration.elmah.errorMail)
{
    $item.from = 'test1@test1.org'
    $item.to = 'test2@test2.org'
    $item.subject = 'test3'
}
$xmlDoc.Save("$path\Web.config")
```